# Running apps on heroku in 'http' instead of 'https'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have deployed the demo app of Michael Hartl's tutorial code onto heroku to see its working.
The app opens in https://some-app-name.herokuapp.com. How do i get it to open in http rather than https?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same problem. You have to change ssl settings for your app.

In `environments/production.rb` there must be following configuration `config.force_ssl = false` which by default is set to true.

Had to reset Firefox to take effect.  Other browsers were ok.

Comment: This answer is also related with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12764627/675577